# How enterprises distribute updates for Linux machines?

Tags: linux

In my use-case, I have Ubuntu machine which is part of organization network but disconnected from the Internet. Yet, somehow it should receive security updates.

How it is usually done in enterprises?

(for example, I know that for Windows machines IT distribute updates via Windows Update. Is there something similar for Linux?)

Comment: apt-mirror for debian/ubuntu f.e.

Comment: Landscape.   Or do it yourself with apt-mirror.   Or  apt-offline if there is no IP network.

Comment: Running a local mirror (apt-mirror) or only requested packages (apt-cacher-ng)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about rpm based distribution as the main one Debian has no editor behind it, but for Red Hat Enterprise Linux you can use [Satellite](https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-satellite)

It makes it possible to use your Red Hat subscription and then use it to register your RHEL machines. You can also push updates to the machines.